# unable to save remote ip address in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am having a weird issue: I want to save site visitor's IP address to database.below i am saying if visitor is not me (61.68.257.80 is my IP address), then save IP address to database. its worked fine when i checked by hiding my proxy. it was saving the ip addresses except mine, but when i visited the website from phone(with phone internet not WiFi) which has different IP address then it is not stored into database. Anyone?

```
$visitor=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      if($visitor!=="61.68.257.80"){
           $count="SELECT * FROM `visitor`";
           $countRun=mysqli_query($conn,$count);
             while($countRow=mysqli_fetch_array($countRun)){
                   $current_counts=$countRow['counts'];
                   $new_count=$current_counts+1;
                 }
            $remote_ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $queryUpdate="INSERT INTO `visitor`(`counts`,`ip_address`)VALUES('".$new_count."','".$remote_ip."')";
            $runUpdate=mysqli_query($conn,$queryUpdate);

        }
```

Comment: check for errors on the query

Comment: First var_dump($visitor) to see what is stored in that variable.

Comment: OMG  bro ! used var_dump and it gave me "string(13) then ip address" while in database its varchar(12). i am an idiot ! thank you so much this is the best answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One small suggestion to improve your code, meanwhile it will be faster too,

What you are doing is getting entire table records, and looping it and finally getting last record's counts, probably that could be maximum value.

So instead of this :

```
 $count="SELECT * FROM `visitor`";
           $countRun=mysqli_query($conn,$count);
             while($countRow=mysqli_fetch_array($countRun)){
                   $current_counts=$countRow['counts'];
                   $new_count=$current_counts+1;
                 }
```

You can just modify your query like below :

```
$count = "select max(counts) as count_max_value from visitor";
```

Above query will return just one row/record which you can access using key `count_max_value`.

For comments:

> used var_dump and it gave me "string(13) then ip address" while in
>   database its varchar(12).

You can modify your table using below query (for an IPv4 address)

```
ALTER TABLE `visitor` MODIFY `ip_address` VARCHAR(15);
```

Comment: checking  var_dump($visitor)  solved problem .but this is something i didn't know too.thanks

Comment: @judy you are welcome, it happens sometimes, and we learn, have a good day, ok hope you could fix

Comment: @judy updated post, with query to modify table, hope this can help you